# Output from remote server at command prompt

Tags: shell, redis

I can connect to remote redis using the telnet command and get the value of "mytest" key. The following is working as expected.

```
[root@server shantanu]# telnet 10.10.10.100 6379
Trying 10.10.10.100...
Connected to 10.10.10.100 (10.10.10.100).
Escape character is '^]'.
get mytest
$14
this is first
```

But how do I use it in shell script?
I am used to connect to mysql using the following:

```
msyql -h10.10.10.100 -uroot -proot@123 -e"show databases"
```

Is a simialar syntax available for redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternatively use `redis-cli`, included in redis

```
$ ./src/redis-cli --raw GET key
test
```

Comment: Thanks for the "--raw" tip. But I need to connect to the remote server. The above command will connect me to the local server. Right?

Comment: You can override that with -h <hostname> -p <port>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know telnet, but with ssh you can:

```
ssh user@server "command arg1 arg2 ..."
```

for example

```
ssh user@server "ls -ltr | tail"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tool like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html), which is designed to get content from websites, and is very configurable and automaetable.  You might even be able to get away with

```
export myTestKey=`echo "get mytest" | telnet 10.10.10.100 6379`
```

If the conversation needs to be more complex than that, I would use telnet in combination with [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/), which is designed for trigger and response conversations.